# How to copy file from one PC to another

Tags: java

I am trying this code to transfer file from my computer to another computer but i am getting 
Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: \192.168.1.4\D:\Color.txt (The network name cannot be found)

```
    File source = new File("G:\\Color.txt");

    File dest = new File("\\\\192.168.1.4\\D:\\Color.txt");
 // File dest = new File("D:\\Color.txt");


    try {

        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(source);

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dest);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {

            output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);

        }
        System.out.println("File Copied successfully");
        input.close();
        output.close();

    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
          System.out.println("Exception "+e);
    }
```

Comment: Does it connect when you manually write that in the explorer?

Answer (score 1):

A file or a directory in the file system is represented by two abstract concepts in java. These abstract concepts are `java.io.File` and `java.nio.file.Path`.

The File class represents a file in the file system whereas the interface Path represents the path string of the file. In this tutorial we look at various operations on File or Path. We get a handle on the File using

Syntax :

```
File file = new File("c:\\filefolder\\file.txt");
```

But in your case first check whether location is available through file explorer,and use the same address.

[image]

Comment: I tried but file location not available through file explorer.actually I am new bee to java.I want to know is it possible to pass ip in file constructor as i did.if not is there any other way to do this

Comment: @seema first find the location you have to save,then try to implement in programming.If you cannot access the location then how come you can write?..If possible try in your local system and then go for LAN

Comment: On local system  I am able copy file using File dest = new File("D:\\Color.txt");    My Question is if i want to copy on different PC then how to do it